# iPhone: beyond bounds [0 .. 8]'

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray

This is driving me crazy!  I keep crashing with this error. Below is my code. I am trying to put an extra cell in my UITabelView for a "25 more" feature.  But I crash below inside of the heightForRowAtIndexPath function.  What am I overlooking?

TIA.

> [NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index
>   4294967295 beyond bounds [0 .. 8]'
>
> 0   CoreFoundation
>   0x01338be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
>     1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x0148d5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
>     2   CoreFoundation
>   0x0132e6e5 -[__NSArrayM
>   objectAtIndex:] + 261     3
>   mackdabMobile
>   0x00004f56
>   -[AllmackTableViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] +

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
    {
        NSLog(@"IndexRow int: %i", indexPath.row);
        NSLog(@"postsArray count: %i", [postsArray count]);
        if(indexPath.row < [postsArray count]){  **<----Where it crashes**
            Post *myPost = [postsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] - 1];
            NSString *text = myPost.description;

            CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 88.0f);

            CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

            CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 35.0f);

            return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2) + 28.0f;
        }else{
            return 100.0f;
        }


    }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


        // Return 1 section which will be used to display the giant blank UITableViewCell as defined
        // in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method below
        if ([self.postsArray count] == 0){

            return 1;

        } else if ([self.postsArray count] < 25) { //self.webServiceDataModel.total

            // Add an object to the end of the array for the "Load more..." table cell.
            NSLog(@"postsArray count: %i", [postsArray count]);
            return [self.postsArray count] + 1;
            NSLog(@"postsArray count after +1: %i", [postsArray count]);

        }   
        // Return the number of rows as there are in the postsArray Post data is empty.
        return [self.postsArray count];

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[indexPath row] - 1` is the problem,

For indexpath.row=0 it will be -1.

`[array objectAtIndex:-1]` is exception. So crash occurs.

Answer (score 1):

When `indexPath.row` is zero, you're trying to fetch the item at index -1 from the array...